# How to use wait()/notify() in Java

Tags: java, wait, notify

I know that there are a few threads open regarding this topic, but I'm just looking for a VERY ELEMENTARY example of how to use wait() and notify() in Java.  By "VERY ELEMENTARY," I mean simply printing something out.  Thanks.

EDIT: Here's what I have tried thus far and I get an IllegalMonitorStateException:

```
public void waiting() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if(i == 5)
                try {
                    this.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    
                }
            else
                System.out.println(i);
        }
        System.out.println("notify me now");    
        this.notify();
}
```

Comment: note that notify() wakes up 1 thread, while notifyAll() wakes up all threads waiting on the given object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**wait and notify are used in synchronized block** while using threads to suspend and resume where left off.

**Wait immediately looses the lock, whereas Nofity will leave the lock only when the ending bracket is encountered.**

```
public class Mythread implements Runnable{



public synchronized void goo(){

System.out.println("Before Wait");

wait();

System.out.println("After Wait");


}


public synchronized void foo(){

System.out.println("Before Notify");

notify();

System.out.println("After Notify");

}


public class Test{

public static  void main(String[] args){

Thread t = new Thread(new Mythread);

t.start();

 }
}
```

Comment: @jrad How to use? you mean just the mechanics of using `wait()`/ `notify()`? Looks like, you would like to know, when to use `wait()`/`notify()` vis-a-vis `synchronized`?

Answer (score 2):

Your IllegalMonitorStateException is due to the fact that you must synchronize on the object before calling wait or notify.  So

`this.wait`

needs to be

```
   synchronized(this) {
      this.wait();
    }
```

Your example won't run because you'll never get to the `notify` call... as soon as your thread hits wait, it will suspend and advance no further.  For wait / notify to work, you have to have two threads.  One thread suspends when the `wait` method is invoked, and eventually, the second thread calls `synchronized(this) { this.notify() }` to cause the first thread to wake up and continue executing below the wait call.

The synchronization is required because you would ordinarily check some condition before waiting, ie,

```
  synchronized(this) { 
      if(! this.isReady) {
         this.wait(); 
      }
   }
```

You need to synchronize to make sure no other thread changes the state of the isReady flag between the line where you check the variable and the line where you wait.  So your notify code would

```
   synchronized(this) {
      isReady = true;
      this.notify();
   }
```

Now the order of the method calls doesn't matter.  If you notify first, no thread will wake up, but that's ok, because you aren't going to sleep since isReady = true.  If you go to sleep first, isReady = true does nothing, but the notify call wakes up the thread.  Finally, the synchronization ensures that you don't check the variable in thread A, then have thread B set the variable and notify (doing nothing), then have thread A go to sleep and never wake up.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

`wait()` and `notify()` are used to synchronise threads: a thread can be told to `wait()`, and will not continue doing anything until it receives the `notify()` call.

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking for an example.

Comment: @JackRadcliffe have you attempted anything yourself?

Comment: Yes, I've added it to the original post.

Comment: And in retrospect, my attempt doesn't make any sense since after it waits, it never leaves the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea with these functions is that `wait()` suspends a thread (puts it to sleep), and `notify()` causes a thread to pick up where it left when it went to sleep.